# Keep current month selected in slicer in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a slicer having a list of MONTH-YEAR list like this:

```
Jul-22
Aug-22
Sep-22
Oct-22
...
...
```

From the above list i want current month to be selected.

I have tried with the code below:-

```
CurrMonth = if(month([Date])=Month(NOW()),month([Date]))
```

and got the current month but not able to set in the slicer.
any help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CurrMonth =

VAR _thismonthstart = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)
VAR _thismonthfinish = EOMONTH(_thismonthstart,0)
return
if [Date] >= _thismonthstart && [Date] <= _thismonthfinish then 1 else 0
```

alternatively, you can use the Filter on the visual

[image: this month]

another alternative is to create a custom *Special Dates Table* which has a cross filter direction both ways with your date table.

[Sample Solution](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/custom-range-date-slicer-power-bi-dynamic-defaults-more-a%C5%9F%C4%B1ro%C4%9Flu/)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution as below:

```
CurrMonth = if(month([Date])=Month(NOW()),CurMonth,FORMAT([Date], "MMM") & " " & [Year])
```

and set CurrMonth as the Field of the Slicer.

Comment: Your formula does not ensure selection of only one value in your slicer.

Answer (score 0):

```
CurrMonth =
IF (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( [Date] ) = FORMAT ( NOW (), "mmm-yy" ),
    [Date],
    FORMAT ( NOW (), "mmm-yy" )
)
```